# Gstreamer Setting File Source from function with const char pointer

Tags: c, gstreamer

problem is if I set the same values for the charArray members there will be no errors, but if I give different values for the array members, for example charArray[0] = "x", charArray[1] = "y" ..it gives me and error with the message below,

"Program has been terminated receiving signal 6 (Aborted)"

Here is the code block that I use,

```
    char *charArray[2]; //global

    static void video_add(GstElement *mixer,int top,int left,int index){

      ....

      src = gst_element_factory_make ("filesrc", NULL);
      g_object_set (G_OBJECT (src), "location", charArray[index], NULL);

      ...
    }

void play(){

.....

 charArray[0] = "/root/yu.mp4";
 charArray[1] = "/root/asd.mpg";
 video_add (videomixer,-300,-310,0);
 video_add (videomixer,-20,-20,1);

.....


}
```

Also if I update my function like this

`static void video_add(GstElement *mixer,int top,int left,char *filePath)`, result is the same,
while

```
video_add (videomixer,-300,-310,"/root/a.mpg");
 video_add (videomixer,-20,-20,1,"/root/a.mpg");
```

generate no errors ,

```
 video_add (videomixer,-300,-310,"/root/a.mpg");
 video_add (videomixer,-20,-20,1,"/root/b.mpg");
```

gives me the same error "Program has been terminated receiving signal 6 (Aborted)".

Comment: Have you tried running your program with gdb (or printing some debug info yourself) to see where it actually fails?